# Real TTY Driver installation - Moxa 5110 not able to connect /dev/ttyr01: Input/output error

Tags: pi-4, serial, driver

trying to get my Moxa Nport 5110 to work with the RPI4.
Currently Using:

- Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- installed moxa-real-tty-drivers-for-linux-kernel-5.x-v5.1
- added some tty ports automatically (according the readme.txt file from moxa)

Module installation and driver installation without any problems. (in my opinion)

```
enter root@raspberrypi:/home# modinfo npreal2
filename:       /lib/modules/5.10.103-v7l+/kernel/drivers/char/npreal2.ko
license:        GPL
version:        Ver5.1
description:    MOXA Async/NPort Server Family Real TTY Driver
name:           npreal2


enter root@raspberrypi:/home# ls -las /dev/ttyr00
0 crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 33, 0 Dec 30 14:13 /dev/ttyr00
root@raspberrypi:/home# ls -las /dev/ttyr01
0 crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 33, 1 Dec 30 14:13 /dev/ttyr01
```

Then I was trying to test the device:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home# stty -F /dev/ttyr00
stty: /dev/ttyr00: Input/output error
```

Can not connect. ALso tried with PuttY.
I was able to find some error logs but honestly ... did not find something usefull to solve the problem and I am a nooby working with RPI/Linux

Debug.log:

```
Dec 30 17:03:39 raspberrypi kernel: [10231.786105] MX(890,npreal_open) npreal_startup failed(-62)
```

npreal2d.log:

```
12-30-2022 14:13:05  MOXA Real TTY daemon program starting (Ver5.1 Build 21080410)...
12-30-2022 14:13:05  MOXA Real TTY daemon program starting (Ver5.1 Build 21080410)...
12-30-2022 17:03:39  Socket connect fail (192.168.100.18,TCP port 4001) !
12-30-2022 17:03:39  Socket connect fail (192.168.100.18,TCP port 4001) !
```

Any sugestions I could test and make difference ? What could I share to pinpoint the problem more precisely?

Before I had installed: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) + npreal2_v5.1.7_build_22021410 - with the same result.

Thx in advance for some support.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Installing worked fine and with out any error messages.

Where I made a mistake was when adding the port using ./mxaddsvr [ip-adress] [no_ports]. I specified the number of ports as 1, which didnt produce an error message, but i couldnt open the port. I deleted it and tried again with 4 Ports. After that I could use putty to send commands and recieve data.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing with the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Maybe try [this solution](https://www.moxa.com/en/support/product-support/product-faq/when-i-install-the-nport-real-tty-driver-on-debian-i-see-error-message) and see if it works. (for me not, but who knows...)